# model is never updating inside controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Here is `app.js`

```
  .state('search', {
      url: '/search',
      templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/home.html',
      controller: 'SearchController'
  })  

  .state('search/search-form', {
      url: '/search/search-form',
      templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/search-form.html',
      controller: 'SearchController'
  })

  .state('search/search-form-settings', {
      url: '/search/search-form-settings',
      templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/search-form-settings.html',
      controller: 'SearchController'
  })  

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/search');
```

`home.html`

```
<ion-view>
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-search" href="#search/search-form"></a>
</ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="padding">    
        <div ng-repeat="data in searchResult">
                {{data.title}}
        </div>     
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

On clicking searh button below page is opened.

`searchForm.html`:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right">
  <button class="button button-icon icon ion-android-done" ng-disabled="npubmUsrLocForm.form.$invalid"  ng-click="searchByTag()"></button>  
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

here is `searchControllet.js` :

```
  $scope.searchResult = [{title:"this is 1"},{title:"this is 2"}];
  alert("init");
    $scope.searchByTag = function()
    {

    $scope.searchResult.push({title:"this is 3"});
    $scope.searchResult.push({title:"this is 4"});
    $state.go('search');
    alert($scope.searchResult.length);
```

in this alert it show lengh 4 but in HTML page it only render `{title:"this is 1"},{title:"this is 2"}`

Answer (score 1):

two things that need to be fixed are your states and your urls:

```
.state('search', {
  url: '/search',
  templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/home.html',
  controller: 'SearchController'
})  

.state('search.search-form', {
  url: '/search-form',
  templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/search-form.html',
  controller: 'SearchController'
})

.state('search.search-form-settings', {
  url: '/search-form-settings',
  templateUrl: 'templates/search-pages/search-form-settings.html',
  controller: 'SearchController'
})  

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/search');
```

The states should be in format 'parent.child' not 'parent/child'.

The urls are relative from the parent url.

Then your HTML should probably be something like:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <a class="button button-icon icon ion-android-search" ui-sref="search.search-form"></a>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
  <ion-content class="padding">   
    <ui-view/> 
    <div ng-repeat="data in searchResult">
            {{data.title}}
    </div>     
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: `ui-sref="search.search-form"` is not navigating to `search-form.html`